# Having some trouble with float in C

Tags: c

I'm having some trouble with float because whenever I enter a decimal number, the program just ends. When I don't and enter an integer, it works perfectly fine (My compiler is codeblocks)

Here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   float kmm; /* Monthly traveled Kilometers  */
   float costo; /* Cost for a liter of gas*/
   float kmp; /* Traveled Kilometers with a liter of gas*/
   float ln; /* Needed liters monthly */
   float costot; /* Monthly total cost*/
   float costom; /*Average daily cost*/

   printf("Enter traveled monthly Kms\n");
   scanf("%f", &kmm);

   printf("Enter cost for a liter of gas\n");
   scanf("%f", &costo);

   printf("Enter traveled Kms with a single liter\n");
   scanf("%f", &kmp);

   ln=kmm/kmp;  /* Needed liters monthly */
   costot=ln*costo;
   printf("La spesa mensile totale è %.3f\n", costot);

   costom=costot/30;
   printf("Il costo medio giornaliero è %.3f\n", costom);

   return 0;
}
```

Can you explain what's going wrong?

UPDATE: I edited in English.

Comment: Don't use commas for decimal point: `42.18` instead of `42,18`. Also always check the return value of `scanf()`: `if (scanf("%f", &kmm) != 1) /* error */;`

Comment: What exactly do you type?  `123.45` or `123,45` or some other notation?  If you use a comma, you probably need to add `#include <locale.h>` and `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` (or perhaps `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, ""):`) to pick up the local convention for the decimal point.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. What do you mean by checking the return value of scanf?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I type in 123.45 but it still doesn't work

Comment: The updated comment shows what to do — if `scanf()` returns 1, then the number was read OK; otherwise, there was a problem.

Comment: @DavideScarpati Please update the question with the exact input you are giving the program. Preferably a copy/paste of the console text.

Comment: In what way "it still doesn't work"?  Doesn't wait for all the input?  Crashes without printing any data?  (Also, these are comments, not answers.  We don't yet understand your problem well enough to write an answer.  Does the program work when you run it in a terminal window instead of via CodeBlocks?)

Comment: I tried your code in repl.it and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @DavideScarpati Add `printf("%f\n", 12.34);` at the start of your program, and tell us what exactly the output is. Copy/paste the output.

Comment: Do you have environment variables like `LANG` or `LC_ALL` or `LC_NUMERIC` set by any chance — if so, what are they set to?  (This shouldn't matter, but it looks as though the code should work, too.) Also, which platform are you working on, and which compiler is Code::Blocks configured to use?

Comment: @Jabberwocky 12.340000Inserire Km percorsi mensilmente

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I installed it yesterday, everything is set by default

Comment: UPDATE: It seems to be working with decimal numbers now. Weird, I basically didn't change anything apart from Jabberwocky's printf

Comment: @DavideScarpati try following little program, type `12.34` and show the verbatim output you get. `#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  float foo;
  int bar = scanf("%f", &foo);
  printf("bar = %d, fo =<%f>\n", bar, foo);
}`

Comment: It's an hour past bedtime here — I'm going to duck out for a few hours and hope others can help you (my brain is fried).  You've not said which o/s you're using nor which compiler; I don't know how important that is.  I think the output you got from the extra `printf()` indicates that the program is configured to use the C locale with `.` (dot) as the decimal point, as you're typing.  I'm not sure what else could be going wrong.  You aren't typing subscript digits in a Unicode (UTF-8) terminal or something funny like that, are you?

Comment: @4386427 I was trying to input decimal numbers at the questions the program asked me and as soon as I entered them, the program would end. integer numbers worked just fine.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Nono, everything I'm using is "normal". Anyway, something did the magic because everything works now. Thank you for your time, really

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP wrote a comment that the problem has gone away magically.

Comment: Again, thank you for your time everyone